# How to round a number and make it show zeros?

Tags: r

The common code in R for rounding a number to say 2 decimal points is:

```
> a = 14.1234 
> round(a, digits=2)
> a
> 14.12
```

However if the number has zeros as the first two decimal digits, R suppresses zeros in display:

```
> a = 14.0034
> round(a, digits=2)
> a
> 14
```

How can we make R to show first decimal digits even when they are zeros? I especially need this in plots. I've searched here and some people have suggested using `options(digits=2)`, but this makes R to have a weird behavior.

Comment: The code `format(round(a), nsmall = 2)` is not sufficient and it should be `format(round(a, 2), nsmall = 2)`. Since `round(a)` rounds all decimal digits, but `round(a, 2)` rounds up to 2 decimal digits. Try `a=1.987` for example.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

We can use `format`

```
format(round(a), nsmall = 2)
#[1] "14.00"
```

As @arvi1000 mentioned in the comments, we may need to specify the `digits` in `round`

```
format(round(a, digits=2), nsmall = 2)
```

#### data

```
a <- 14.0034
```

Comment: Actually, I think this should be `format(round(a, digits=2), nsmall = 2)`, because OP wants to preserve any zeros after the decimal point when correctly rounded to 2 places, not round to 0 places and then pad with two trailing zeros. Compare: `format(round(14.0123), nsmall = 2)` (wrong)
and `format(round(14.0123,digits = 2), nsmall = 2)`

Comment: oh, as the OP already pointed out in a comment on the question above. You may want to edit, esp since it's the accepted answer

Comment: @arvi1000  Thanks for the suggestion.  I almost forgot about the `round` part

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
a = 14.0034 
sprintf('%.2f',a) # 2 digits after decimal
# [1] "14.00"
```

Comment: Just `sprintf('%.2f', a)` will do the rounding too I believe. `sprintf('%.2f', 14.009)` gives `"14.01"` for instance.

Answer (score 4):

The formatC function works nicely if you apply it to the vector after rounding. Here the inner function `round` rounds to two decimal places then the outer function `formatC` formats to the same number of decimal places as the number were rounded to. This essentially re-adds zeros to the number that would otherwise end without the decimal places (e.g., 14.0034 is rounded to 14, which becomes 14.00).

```
a=c(14.0034, 14.0056) 
formatC(round(a,2),2,format="f")
#[1] "14.00", "14.01"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: for full information on formatC, one can type ?formatC