# How do I connect a radio button in ui.R and create a datatable on the server.R based off of that radio button?

Tags: r, shiny

So I have been having a hard time trying to connecting a radio button in ui.R and creating a datable on the server.R based off of that radio buttons. Currently, when I run the application, no datable is outputted. I am just wondering what I am doing wrong?

In addition to that issue, how can I also round the mean by using the textinput function in the `ui.R`?

The current radio button options I have are Hours, Age, and Score.

**ui.R**:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Summaries for American Credit"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
             selectInput("variable","Variables to Summarize",
                         c("Hours"="Hours", "Age"="Age",
                           "Score"="Score")),
             textInput("number","Select the number of digits for rounding")
             
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("numericSummary")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$numericSummary = renderTable({
  var = input$variable
  AmericanCreditSub <- AmericanCredit[, c("Class", "InstallmentRatePercentage", var),
                                drop = FALSE]
  table <- aggregate(AmericanCreditSub[[var]] ~ Class + InstallmentRatePercentage,
                 data = AmericanCreditSub, FUN = mean)
  datatable(table)
  })
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `renderDataTable` instead of `renderTable`. And just call `table` and not `datatable(table)` at the end of your server output.

Comment: Thanks @johnpaul5. Do you know how I could get my text input function to take care of the rounding for the `AmericanCreditSub[[var]]`?

Comment: Yes, use a Numeric input instead of a text input in your UI, and use the `round()` function in your server. Something like `AmericanCreditSub[[var]] <- round(AmericanCreditSub[[var]], digits=input$number)`.
If you need the same number of digits for all numbers in var, use the `format()` function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105336/how-to-round-a-number-and-make-it-show-zeros/42105521)

Comment: Hi @johnpaul5, is there a way to have `AmericanCrediSub[[var]]` show up as the "Average  Age/Score/Hours" as supposed to AmericanCrediSub[[var]]?

Comment: Well, not sure what you want to achieve... A minimal reproducible example of your AmericanCredit dataframe would help as well as an example of result you want

Comment: Hi @johnpaul5, just wanted to say I was able to resolve it using the setNames function.